# TextView is not showing on android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have created an stopwatch app. When I run this app on my tab( android os kitkat) it works fine. Here is the screenshot of my android app running on tab.

[tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFue4.png)

But when I run the same app on android vertual device (os pie) it does not show the content of the textView. Here is the screenshot of my android virtual device.

[android emulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeDg2.jpg)

here is my xml code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StopwatchActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_view"
        android:layout_width="231dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/start_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
        android:text="@string/start"
        android:onClick="onClickStart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/stop_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/time_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/time_view" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
        android:text="@string/stop"
        android:onClick="onClickStop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/reset_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/start_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/start_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="241dp"
        android:text="@string/reset"
        android:onClick="onClickReset"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/stop_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/stop_button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Add your xml code here

Comment: I have added the xml code. Have you found anything? i don't think there is any problem in xml file.

Comment: It seems problem in your xml only. Height should not be match_constraint. Keep it wrap_content and then try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your textview height to 0dp. That is the problem.

Solution:
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: Thanks it worked. And you were right. but i want to know why the same code worked on my device event if the heigh was set to 0dp.

Comment: Thats because of your margin attr values in the textview. Due to this, the layout exists and will be visible on devices with bigger screen sizes and not on smaller screen in your case, seen on tablet and not on device

Comment: @user192183 you might set another constraint in your  screen by this way it might be visible but same constraint might not applied to another one and that might not be visible.